# How Node js connect read file excel cloud (online)?

Tags: node.js, excel

I have a project using node js, I want to connect to an excel ( cloud ) online file from microsofe. How can read excel file online, listen to file change event.

Please !!!

I tried Point share ! but don't work !
`

```
var url = 'https://myproject.sharepoint.com/personal/name';  
var username = "username@microsoft.com.";  
var password = "*******";  


app.get('/',(req,res,next) => {
    console.log(req.connection.remoteAddress)
   spauth.getAuth(url, {          
    username:username,  
    password:password  
})  
.then(function(options){  
     // Access Token will be available on the options.headers variable
     var listTitler="OP Production Tracking Online Ver3.1";
       


     var headers = options.headers;  
     headers['Accept'] = 'application/json;odata=verbose';  
     // Pull the SharePoint list items  
     requestprom.get({  
     url: url+"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listTitler+"')",  
         headers: headers,  
         json: true  
     }).then(function(listresponse){  
         var items = listresponse.d.Title;  
         var responseJSON = [];  
         // process  
           
        
         console.log(JSON.stringify(listresponse))
       //  response.end( JSON.stringify ( listresponse ));  
           
    
 });   
});  
`
```

Comment: I think you have to try first and ask some issues when you tried.

Comment: "doesn't work" means nothing. Please explain how it didn't work and post any error messages

Comment: ERROR : Please

Unhandled rejection StatusCodeError: 404 - {"error":{"code":"-1, System.ArgumentException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"List 'OP Production Tracking Online Ver3.1' does not exist at sit
e with URL 'https://myprojec.sharepoint.com/personal/name'."}}}
    at new StatusCodeError (C:\Users\MEDCPham\Documents\opmevn\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\errors.js:32:15)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Excel JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-worksheets) to read and track any changes in your files.
The documentation provide you plenty of methods that you can use to play with the Excel Sheets.

Comment: This is a great document, but the Excel file is in an Onedrive Folder, not in Office 365. I have enough info to connect but don't know how ??? Please! :(

Comment: @CôngPhạm can you move the excel sheet from one drive to Google Sheets? Quite honestly I have worked on google sheet apis and it is very easy to implement and easy to understand.

Comment: I have also tried switching to Sheet but I am not the admin of that excel file so I cannot get the online user input